# Java Decode double encoded utf-8 char

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I am parsing a websocket message and due do a bug in a specific socket.io version (Unfortunately I don't have control over the server side), some of the payload is double encoded as utf-8:

The correct value would be **Wrocławskiej** (note the l letter which is LATIN SMALL LETTER L WITH STROKE) but I actually get back **WrocÅawskiej**.

I already tried to decode/encode it again with java

```
String str = new String(wrongEncoded.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Unfortunately the string stays the same. Any idea on how to do a double decoding in java? I saw a python version where they convert it to `raw_unicode` first and then parse it again, but I don't know this works or if there is a similar solution for Java.
I already read through a couple of posts on that topic, but none helped.

Edit: To clarify in Fiddler I receive the following byte sequence for the above mentionend word:

```
WrocÃÂawskiej

byte[] arrOutput = { 0x57, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x63, 0xC3, 0x85, 0xC2, 0x82, 0x61, 0x77, 0x73, 0x6B, 0x69, 0x65, 0x6A };
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by double encoded? Do you mean the string is encoded using codec A, decoded using B, then encoded using A again? It looks like all you're doing is encoding and decoding the string using UTF-8 both times.

Comment: There should be an additional character after the Å. How is the `String` (you call it `wrongEncoded`) created? I wonder if there is a problem there as well as the server side.

Comment: I think you mean that the erroneous behavior is that the original character data are encoded in UTF-8, then the resulting byte sequence is interpreted as character data in another (presumably single-byte) encoding, and that character interpretation is encoded in UTF-8 to obtain the final result.  Supposing that there is no data loss (which is neither clear or certain), we will need to know the details in order to help you with reversing the process.

Comment: I updated my question to include the received bytes. For double encoding I> was refering to this [socket.io bug fix](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-parser/pull/81)
I was debugging this with Fiddler when I saw that the problematic encoded already comes from the server. So I need to find a workaround to solve this at the client side - when I got the string message already

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You text was encoding to UTF-8, those bytes were then interpreted as ISO-8859-1 and re-encoded to UTF-8.

`Wrocławskiej` is unicode: 0057 0072 006f 0063 **0142** 0061 0077 0073 006b 0069 0065 006a
Encoding to UTF-8 it is: 57 72 6f 63 **c5 82** 61 77 73 6b 69 65 6a

In [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout), `c5` is `Å` and `82` is *undefined*.
As ISO-8859-1, those bytes are: `WrocÅawskiej`
Encoding to UTF-8 it is: 57 72 6f 63 **c3 85 c2 82** 61 77 73 6b 69 65 6a
Those are likely the bytes you are receiving.

So, to undo that, you need:

```
String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// fix "double encoding"
s = new String(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Ah okay, I did not think that it could have been reencoded into ISO-8859-1.  Works for me now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem that sometimes I received double encoded strings and sometimes proper encoded strings. The following method fixDoubleUTF8Encoding will handle both properly:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String input = "werewrÃ¤Ã¼Ã¨Ã¶";
  String result = fixDoubleUTF8Encoding(input);
  System.out.println(result); // werewräüèö
  
  input = "üäöé";
  result = fixDoubleUTF8Encoding(input);
  System.out.println(result); // üäöé
}

private static String fixDoubleUTF8Encoding(String s) {
  // interpret the string as UTF_8
  byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  // now check if the bytes contain 0x83 0xC2, meaning double encoded garbage
  if(isDoubleEncoded(bytes)) {
    // if so, lets fix the string by assuming it is ASCII extended and recode it once
    s = new String(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);            
  }
  return s;
}

private static boolean isDoubleEncoded(byte[] bytes) {
  for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    if(bytes[i] == -125 && i+1 < bytes.length && bytes[i+1] == -62) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, double encoding may not be the only issue to deal with. Here is a solution that counts for more then one reason

```
String myString = "heartbroken ð";
                myString = new String(myString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                String cleanedText = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(myString);
                byte[] bytes = cleanedText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                String text = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
                CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
                decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
                decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
                CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
                encoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
                encoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
                try {
                    // The new ByteBuffer is ready to be read.
                    ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(text));
                    // The new ByteBuffer is ready to be read.
                    CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
                    String str = cbuf.toString();
                } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
                    logger.error("Error Message if you want to");

                }
```

A